# Modifying the SAX-RSS-Reader to read thumbnail tags

Tags: android, rss-reader

I've tried my best to study several other examples and then figure out what needs to be changed but I have failed so far.

The library project is [here](https://github.com/NickPresta/MyGuelph/tree/master/lib/SAX-RSS-Reader)

It provides a very easy to use RSS Reader library but it doesn't read the media:thumbnail tag (which is what I need).

My question? What do I need to add to the code (the library project) in order to make it read the thumbnail tag too.

I believe the file RssHandler needs to be modified but I just can't figure out what to change.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a new property in RSSItem and a setter name that has the same name as the attribute with "set" at the front.

For example:

```
public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
}
```

The RSSHandler will look for this method when parsing through the attributes.